# How to select the multiple row in jQuery data table using the shift key

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I need to select multiple rows in a jQuery data table using the shift-key, the same as the shift-key select function, and store the selected row items in a variable.  Also I need to select multiple rows using a click event.

Using a single variable, I need to pass the live click rows and shift selection rows. How I do that?

This is not working properly and does not store a single variable for the selected rows. Where am I wrong?

My Code:

```
var aSelected = [];
var lastSelected;

$('#table tr').live('click', function (event) {
    var tableRow = $(this).closest("tr").prevAll("tr").length + 1;

    var id = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
    var index = jQuery.inArray(id, aSelected);
    if (index === -1) {
        aSelected.push(id);
    } else {
        aSelected.splice(index, 1);
    }

    $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');

    if (event.shiftKey) {
        var table = $('#table ');
        var start = Math.min(tableRow, lastSelected);
        var end = Math.max(tableRow, lastSelected);

        for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            $('#table').each(function () {
                table.find('tr:gt(' + (start - 1) + '):lt(' + (end) + ')').addClass('row_selected');
            });
        }

    } else {

        lastSelected = $(this).closest("tr").prevAll("tr").length + 1;
    }
});
```

For example I have 20 rows. There are 3 cause I select the rows and passing the selected row id 1. using Ctrl key select the multiple rows and passing 2. using shift key select the next by next 10 rows and passing 3. using shift key select the next by next 10 rows and extra 2 rows using Ctrl key other 10 rows and passing the 12 rows

Comment: aSelected.splice(index, 1); you use this line of code, but yo didn't add any content into the aSelected, what you purpose of this line of code?

Comment: just remove the already selected row . Thats y use this line

Answer (score 1):

use the following code

```
     $('#tableId').dataTable( {

    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sRowSelect": "multi",
        "aButtons": [ "select_all", "select_none" ]
    }
} );
```

by using this code you select multiple rows with out using shift key

Comment: but how i am pass the selected row id to my controller

Comment: you need to pass one id or multiple id's

Comment: i need to sen the multiple id. Some time i select the row just shift key and some time using Ctrl. In some time using shift key 10 rows and using Ctrl 2 rows  totally 12 rows .I so collapse these are condition how to send the data Ctrl and shift row selection same id

Comment: For example i have 20 rows. there are 3 cause i select the rows and passing the selected row id 1. using Ctrl key select the multiple rows and passing 2. using shift key select the next by next 10 rows and passing 3. using shift key select the next by next 10 rows and extra 2 rows using Ctrl key other 10 rows and passing the 12 rows

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    shiftKey=false;
    if (e.shiftKey) shiftKey=true;
} 
dataTableID='yourDataTable';
$('#'+dataTableID).DataTable().on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {                        
    thisID=e.currentTarget.id;
    selecting=$('#'+thisID).attr('selecting');
    if (typeof(selecting)=="undefined" || selecting=="false"){
        idx=indexes[0];
        lastSelected=$('#'+thisID).attr('lastSelected');
               
        if (shiftKey==true) {
            $('#'+thisID).attr('lastSelected',idx);
            if (typeof(lastSelected)!="undefined" && lastSelected !='') {   
                min=idx+1;
                max=lastSelected;
                if (max<min) {
                    tmp=min;
                    min=max;
                    max=tmp;                
                }
                if (min<max) {
                    $('#'+thisID).attr('selecting',"true");
                    for (x=min;x<max;x++) $('#'+thisID).DataTable().row( x ).select();
                    $('#'+thisID).attr('selecting',"false");                                    
                }
            }
        } else {
            $('#'+thisID).attr('lastSelected','');
        }
    }                    
});
$('#'+settings.sTableId).DataTable().on( 'deselect', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {                        
    thisID=e.currentTarget.id;
    $('#'+thisID).attr('lastSelected','');                 
});
```